# SQL how to create a flag which shows where a record start date falls between a start and end date of another row based on a key field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data which has multiple rows per person, start and end dates, and some start and end dates overlap. I am trying to create a flag which highlights the rows of the latest record. I am thinking row_number might work, but I am blanking on how to formulate it correctly. Any help welcome please!

Example data

```
ID  START       END        FLAG REQUIRED
1   01/01/2020  01/01/2021    2
1   01/11/2020  01/01/2022    1
2   01/01/2020  01/01/2022    1
2   01/02/2021  01/12/2021    2
```

I hope this makes sense, any questions please ask.

Comment: Seems you could check if the end date is *after* the start date of the next row using `LEAD`/`LAG`.

Comment: "a flag which highlights the rows of the latest record" what does that mean?

Comment: @Charlieface The latest record meaning the one which has the latest end date

Comment: @ThomA the records in the real dataset won't be ordered, so not possible to do it that way unfortunately.

Comment: `LAG`/`LEAD` require an `ORDER BY`, @Countrygirl , they *must* be ordered. Same for `ROW_NUMBER`. If you can't order your data (on the start date?) then what does that date represent? Some arbitrary value?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

SELECT
ID,
START,
END,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY END DESC) AS FLAG_REQUIRED
FROM
your_table_name;

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using reserved keywords like END... :

```
CREATE TABLE YourTableName (
  ID INT,
  STARTDATE DATE,
  ENDDATE DATE
);


INSERT INTO YourTableName (ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE)
VALUES
  (1, '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'),
  (1, '2020-01-11', '2022-01-01'),
  (2, '2020-01-01', '2022-01-01'),
  (2, '2021-01-02', '2021-01-12');
SELECT
  ID,
  STARTDATE,
  ENDDATE,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ENDDATE DESC) AS FLAG_REQUIRED
FROM
  YourTableName;
```

| ID | STARTDATE | ENDDATE | FLAG_REQUIRED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-11 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-12 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SDV5Jj9v)